# Group by MonetDB R issue

Tags: r, monetdb

Can MonetDB aggregate functions return more than 1 value per group?

I guess either one row, many columns or 1 column many rows or both would be preferred. I think the answer is no, but just checking.

Another possibility is to evaluate a function over a partition of the dataset?

---

EDIT: This function would do it.

dbSendQuery(conn,"CREATE aggregate linear_model(y double,x double) RETURNS string LANGUAGE R {
      library(data.table)

```
  library(rjson)

  v=data.table(aggr_group,y,x)[,list(coefficients=coef(lm(y ~ x))),by=list(aggr_group)]

  v=split(v,as.factor(aggr_group))

  unlist(lapply(v,toJSON))

};")
```

JSON can be used to (most likely data lossless-ly) serialize a list.